Why does internal covariate shift affect neural networks when the loss landscape remains the same?
Why does internal covariate shift affect neural networks when the loss landscape remains the same? When reading about internal covariate shift and how batch normalization doesn't really solve it, it struck me that I don't really understand why internal covariate shift is an issue practically. Theoretically, it is like chasing a running target, which is harder than chasing a static one, but practically, what are the mathematical complications? I mean, the loss landscape should remain the same even though the distributions between layers change.
